# Is After Effects capable to show me every asset in the projects library that is NOT used in active comp?

Tags: after-effects

Is it possible to delete all unused assets in the projects panel from after effects?

Answer (score 2):

With the desired composition selected in the *Project Panel*, go to: 
*File > Dependencies > Reduce Project*:

[image]

Comment: you wish to "display all unused assets" , so which of the options in that submenu do that?

Comment: @Mulvya well, my question wasn't quite precise. I actually wanted to select all unused assets to kill them from the project. I will update the question.